# Most performant way to check if a token is part of a whitelist

Tags: java, regex

I'm processing a high volume of string tokens, one at a time. I only want to do additional, more expensive, processing on a small subset of the tokens, for the sake of example, only tokens with the substring "cat" in them. The set of possible tokens is finite and I could enumerate all the tokens with "cat" in them into a list.

Would it be faster to a) precompile a regex like ".*cat.*" and check if the token matches against that, or b) enumerate all potential valid tokens into a list and every time I process a token, check to see if it's contained in the list?

Thanks for any insight. My Java is rusty :(

Comment: Why a list? A Set seems much more appropriate. In either case, this seems like a question better answered by experiment than theory.

Comment: If you put them in a List, then a regex is probably faster. If you put them in a Set, then it depends on the average length of the token, and the number of hash collisions between the tokens in the HashSet. The HashSet is then *probably* faster.

Comment: Consider that if your regexp really looks like `".*cat.*"` then `String.contains` would be much faster.